# Building Ios Ionic Application In Ubuntu Free

Tags: ios, cordova, ubuntu, ionic-framework, build

I am a student that is taking a research in my school; our panel wants us to develop a hybrid application and they said that there is a way to build an IOS application using Ionic.

I need it to be free because I can't afford the $99.00 per year on the apple cerficate since I'm just a student.

I don't need to distribute in the app store of Ios, I just need to build it and show that it can work.

So what I'm asking is someone who can give me step by step, or point me in the right direction on how to build it.

Edit: I have already built an apk and an android application is already running, but our teacher just deducted points because I can't show a running ios application.

Comment: You can show your out put using APK,  you dont need to publsh your app in any store, you can show your demo your own mobile  try https://ionicframework.com and https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html , https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/ ,https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/testing.html

Comment: @core114 I have already build the APK and the android is already running but our teacher just deducted points  because I can't show my application running in an ios phone.

Comment: have you tried this? https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/206130

Comment: @Dev_Tandel Thank you, I'll try that tonight when I get home and I'll update this thread for any questions.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel Doesn't this require a mac? I don't have any mac that I can borrow and I also can't buy one.

Comment: You can use Virtual Machine.

Comment: you can run in google chrome extension and in that you can show your app in any ios device as ionic have support

Comment: @ravi.p That's what I showed my teacher but he wasn't satisfied at all, he said he needs the actual app on an ios phone.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel Is it possible to have a mac on virtual machine, in ubuntu?

Comment: May this helps : http://suzywu2014.github.io/ubuntu/2017/02/23/macos-sierra-virtualbox-vm-on-ubuntu